# How can i make a Shared File in Playgrounds

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground

I want ot write a console Application on the Playgrounds App on my Ipad. But i don't know how to make a File "Shared" so it can be accessed by the Main. I always get the Error Code: Cannot find type 'Model' in Scope.

I hope you can help me how to fix this.

[image: Image of the Error]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `Model` to `public` in your shared file. The same goes for any properties and functions you want to access in your main code.